# Htaccess for external domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ load.php?id=%1&q=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This is my current code

`subdomain.domain.com/querystring`

The condition is **domain.com**

Is there a way I can achieve the same thing

but the domain.com can be dynamic, means it could be `123456.co` or `qwerty1234.xyz/querystring`

Yet it able capture

```
Domain: qwerty1234.xyz
Query String: querystring
```

How do I make my htaccess to check if domain is not containing `domain.com`, it will use `load.php`

but pass the domain & its query string to load.php as `?domain=$domain&query=$querystring`

Thanks!

Updated .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ load.php?id=%1&q=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)?(css|js|png|jpg|gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ load.php?id=%1&q=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is your issue still? Did you try the answer I put?

Comment: @PanamaJack I tried the code you given, but if I use without www for otherdomain.com, it will load index.php (not working for the .htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add this to your rules. You don't have to do anything special to capture the querystring. Simply keep the `QSA flag` and any additional query string on the request will also be sent to load.php.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.)?(css|js|png|jpg|gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ load.php?domain=%1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Did this help you at all?

Comment: if i use http://otherdomain.com, without www, it will load my load.php instead. any idea how to handle without www for other domain  , with or without www for otherdomain to use load.php

Comment: Well if you don't say what's still not working, then I, nor anyone can't  help you fix it. Now it should be capturing both. It works for me. I tested it with both your rules together [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be)  Provide a better example of what its doing in your question. Actually show examples and the redirection.

Comment: Great. glad you got it.